# UnsatisfiedLinkError "Access is denied" even with Full Control

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, dll

I'm getting a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError from java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load() with the message "Access is denied". The DLL is being loaded from a network share via a UNC path. It previously worked without error on other network shares (I have been told by a sysadmin that this particular share is more "natively Windows"), so my first instinct was to use cacls to grant Full Control on the DLL file both for Everyone and the specific user running the Java code. When I view the DLL Properties in Windows Explorer, it clearly has those permissions set, and yet it is still failing with this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that this dll is, in turn, trying to load other dlls, which have not been given sufficient permissions.

Comment: Hmm... and that wouldn't be reflected in the error message, because at that point the loading is originating in the native code?

Comment: Yup, there was a libdb47.dll in the directory as well. Doing a grant on that with cacls seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Another possibility for people having this issue, some jars extract the DLL files to use them, and need to be extracted to a folder with correct permissions. Like in this case: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/97

Answer (score -1):

Run it as System Administrator and it will work for sure. I had a same problem and ran the Eclipse as Administrator and it worked.

Comment: Running as admin also promotes any per-user security issues in the software into a per-system security issue. This is at best a temporary workaround, and even then only as a last resort.